# VisualVM breaks jetty

Tags: java, maven-2, jetty, visualvm

I'm trying to profile application that is run by "mvn jetty:run", when I connect VisualVM to it and click on Profile jetty crashes with:

```
Profiler Agent: Waiting for connection on port 5140 (Protocol version: 8)
Profiler Agent: Established local connection with the tool
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6da5e5d4, pid=5124, tid=5704
#
# JRE version: 6.0_16-b01
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (14.2-b01 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x1ae5d4]
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# c:\dev\workspaces\credentials\credentialsgui\hs_err_pid5124.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
Profiler Agent: JNI On Load Initializing...
Profiler Agent: JNI OnLoad Initialized succesfully
```

The same thing I get with different application run using mvn jetty:run.

What's funny is that when I used profiler from NetBeans (should be the same as VisualVM) it works correctly, but I would prefer to use VisualVM any hints on fixing this?

VisualVM from jdk 1.6 (but I used also before a downloadable version).

Answer (score 6):

[The documentation for VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/gettingstarted.html?Java_VisualVM) says that if you are using Java 6 you must turn off class sharing when you start the VM:

> To profile an application running on
>   JDK 6, you need to turn off class
>   sharing for the application otherwise
>   the application may crash. To turn off
>   class sharing, start the application
>   with -Xshare:off argument.

I suspect that Maven does not use this option by default when it starts Jetty.

Comment: The link appears to be broken.